# How to make this difference equation continuous?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$ F_n=F_{n-1}-F_{n-2} $$

How can I convert this oscillating sequence into a continuous function? IE get it in terms of n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sequence has exactly 6 values:
($a$,$\ $ $b$, $\ $ $b-a$, $\ $ $-a$, $\ $ $-b$, $\ $ $a-b$) in cycle.

So, there is a reason to build trigonometric function with period of $6$:
$$
F(n) = A \sin \frac{\pi n}{3} + B \cos\frac{ \pi n}{3},
$$

---

If $F_0 = a$, $F_1 = b$, then
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
A\cdot 0 + B\cdot 1 = a;\\
A\cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + B \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} = b; \\
A\cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - B \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} = b-a; \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$ 
$B=a$, $A=\dfrac{2b-a}{\sqrt{3}}$.

So,
$$
F(n) = \dfrac{2b-a}{\sqrt{3}} \cdot \sin \frac{\pi n}{3} \;+ \; a \cdot \cos\frac{\pi n}{3},
$$
where $a=F_0$, $b=F_1$.

Comment: How would this apply to$F_0=1$ and $F_1=2$?

Comment: Just wait a few minutes. I'll expand the answer.

Comment: I get a strange answer for $F(1)$ Are you sure the equation is correct?

Comment: Now all is correct. $F(1) = \dfrac{2b-a}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + a \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{2b-a}{2}+\dfrac{a}{2}=b$; $F(2) = \dfrac{2b-a}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - a \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{2b-a}{2}-\dfrac{a}{2}=b-a$; $\ldots$.

Comment: because $\sin\dfrac{\pi}{3}=\sin\dfrac{2\pi}{3}=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, $\cos\dfrac{\pi}{3}=\dfrac{1}{2}$,$\cos\dfrac{2\pi}{3}=\dfrac{-1}{2}$,  $\ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the solution [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving) of Recurrence relation,

we have $r^2-r+1=0\implies r=\frac{1\pm\sqrt3i}2$

So, if $\lambda_1=\frac{1+\sqrt3i}2, \lambda_2=\frac{1-\sqrt3i}2$

$$F_n=A\cdot \lambda_1^n+B\cdot \lambda_2^n$$ where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants

Let $\frac12=r\cos\theta,\frac{\sqrt3}2=r\sin\theta$ where $r>0$ so that

Squaring & adding we get $r^2=1\implies r=1$ as $r>0$

$\implies \cos\theta=\frac12>0$ and $\sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt3}2>0$

On division $\tan\theta=\sqrt3\implies \theta=\frac\pi3$

So, $\lambda_1=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)=\cos\frac\pi3+i\sin\frac\pi3$

and $\lambda_2=r(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)=\cos\frac\pi3-i\sin\frac\pi3=\cos(-\frac\pi3)+i\sin(-\frac\pi3)$ as $\cos(-x)=\cos x,\sin(-x)=-\sin x$

$\implies \lambda_1^n=(\cos\frac\pi3+i\sin\frac\pi3)^n=\cos \frac{n\pi}3+i\sin\frac{n\pi}3$ using [De Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)

Similarly, $\lambda_2^n=\{\cos(-\frac\pi3)+i\sin(-\frac\pi3)\}^n=\cos(-\frac{n\pi}3)+i\sin(-\frac{n\pi}3)=\cos \frac{n\pi}3-i\sin\frac{n\pi}3$

$$\implies F_n=A\left(\cos \frac{n\pi}3+i\sin\frac{n\pi}3\right)+B\left(\cos \frac{n\pi}3-i\sin\frac{n\pi}3\right)$$
$$=(A+B)\cos \frac{n\pi}3+i(A-B)\sin\frac{n\pi}3$$

Comment: @user86770, you may also avoid $i$ by putting $i(A-B)=C$ as $A,B$ can assume any finite value